# Potential attack vectors on an Ethereum account

Tags: security, accounts, attacks

Besides someone stealing your private key, what are other potential attack vectors on an Ethereum account?

Answer (score 3):

1. getting access to you ipc socket and have this loop running waiting for you to use Mist or anything that unlocks your account (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNSwFy__m-8)
2. same attack for rpc, that's more about opening the --rpc flag and exposing the port to the world
3. keyloggers of course
4. the websocket option seems deadly at first sight

Comment: how can we reduce the attack vector then?